How to sync a branch in SVN without bringing in merged revisions logs
I've been using an SVN server (tortoiseSVN) at work (assume we cannot switch it to git or similar), and we recently implemented the use of feature branches into our development. This seemed to work well, but we are having trouble with the logging:
From the trunk, we would like to see the "merged revisions" for each merge done from a branch. When I select this, I see a garbled mess that is multiple tiers in depth. I believe the issue may be when we sync branches with the trunk (using a merge a range of revisions). This causes the log messages for anything done on the trunk to be pulled into the branch, and then when the branch is committed back to the trunk, they show up as a deeper tier of edit made in the TortoiseSVN logs.
Is there anyway to not bring in these messages when syncing up the branch to the trunk?
(Edit: Adding example @Friedrich)
Example:

Create repo
Import some files F1 and F2
Make branch A
Make branch B
Switch to Branch A. Add a file A1
Switch to Trunk. Merge and commit Branch A.
Switch to Branch B. Add a file B1
Merge revisions from trunk and commit to Branch B.
Switch to trunk. Merge and commit Branch B.

I did this (plus some random "update files" sprinkled in) and the TortoiseSVN log looks like this (with merged revisions):

The tiers do not line up whatsoever, and do not match what it looks like without including merged revisions:

What did I do wrong?

A small example including what you observe may help. Usually, the svn:mergeinfo property would prevent the same commit (and hence log) being applied twice. You might have misconfigured something or found a bug in TortoiseSVN.

@Friedrich Added an example!
